# how to search for file that you know only the first 5 letters of in windows and save the output?

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd, server

for example i need to search for the file 
hidebarVersion0.2.exe
I only know hidebarVersion but 0.2 will change each time ?

So I need to take that name each time and use it in another command like this

hidebarVersion0.2.exe -t -very -near

? how to script this in Windows ?

Comment: You can use the `DIR` or `FOR` commands.

Comment: I don't understand why people are answering this question. There has been no effort shown and it reads like gimmie the codez.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%G in ('dir /a /b /s hidebarVersion*.exe') do "%%G" -t -very -near
```

To use it on the command prompt instead of inside a batch file use this:

```
for /f "delims=" %G in ('dir /a /b /s hidebarVersion*.exe') do "%G" -t -very -near
```

The command `dir /a /b /s hidebarVersion*.exe` finds a file matching hidebarVersion*.exe in the current directory or any of the subdirectories, and returns it in bare (/b) format.

Comment: `... (' dir /a-d /b /s /od hidebarVersion*.exe') do ...`?

Comment: Thanks guys :D it's working now :D.. I hope if there is a python version

Comment: @IbrahimMohamed If you feel like my answer solved your problem, you can click the check to the left of it to mark it as correct, or you can leave a comment with any other errors you get

Answer (score 2):

You can use get-childitem in the Directory to get the exact Name and then start an process with start:

```
$a = get-childitem hidebar* | sort name -desc | select -first 1
start $a.fullname
```

It will run that hidebar*.exe with the highest =newest filename.

Comment: '$a' is not recognized as an in
operable program or batch file.

Comment: @IbrahimMohamed That sounds like a cmd error... not PowerShell.

Comment: @Matt yes exactly what I thought too. Leaving the stack trace will be wise in this scenario.

Comment: The commmands i provided are written in Powershell. In a Windows cmd you will get an error, sure.

Comment: Thanks @Martin i will go with CMD for now